# Cant start my virtual environment of flask through cygwin

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv

Cant start my virtual environment of flask through cygwin :
my system :**(windows 10)**

Method 1:

```
$ env/Scripts/activate
```

Method 2:

```
$ env/Scripts/activate.bat
```

Method 3:

```
$ source ./env/Scripts/activate
```

on my cygwin cli, but it gives the following error all the time :

```
-bash: $'\r': command not found
-bash: ./env/Scripts/activate: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `$'{\r''
'bash: ./env/Scripts/activate: line 4: `deactivate () {
```

**Note :** The first two methods of activating virtual environment works nicely on VSCode but not on cygwin.

My **activate file** :

```
# This file must be used with "source bin/activate" *from bash*
# you cannot run it directly

deactivate () {
    # reset old environment variables
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}" ] ; then
        PATH="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH:-}"
        export PATH
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH
    fi
    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
        PYTHONHOME="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME:-}"
        export PYTHONHOME
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME
    fi

    # This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
    # be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
    # past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
    if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
        hash -r 2> /dev/null
    fi

    if [ -n "${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}" ] ; then
        PS1="${_OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1:-}"
        export PS1
        unset _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1
    fi

    unset VIRTUAL_ENV
    if [ ! "${1:-}" = "nondestructive" ] ; then
    # Self destruct!
        unset -f deactivate
    fi
}

# unset irrelevant variables
deactivate nondestructive

VIRTUAL_ENV="D:\projects\websites\googleHostFlaskApp\env"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/Scripts:$PATH"
export PATH

# unset PYTHONHOME if set
# this will fail if PYTHONHOME is set to the empty string (which is bad anyway)
# could use `if (set -u; : $PYTHONHOME) ;` in bash
if [ -n "${PYTHONHOME:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PYTHONHOME="${PYTHONHOME:-}"
    unset PYTHONHOME
fi

if [ -z "${VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT:-}" ] ; then
    _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="${PS1:-}"
    PS1="(flask) ${PS1:-}"
    export PS1
fi

# This should detect bash and zsh, which have a hash command that must
# be called to get it to forget past commands.  Without forgetting
# past commands the $PATH changes we made may not be respected
if [ -n "${BASH:-}" -o -n "${ZSH_VERSION:-}" ] ; then
    hash -r 2> /dev/null
fi
```

Comment: Cygwin emulates UNIX behavior, and <venv>/Scripts/activate is a script written for windows. Python venvs created in windows do not contain the <venv>/bin/activate script required for UNIX systems.

Comment: but there is no bin folder in my env folder, and my activate file is in Scripts folder... so the solution should be? @ben

Comment: There is no bin folder because the venv was created for windows and is not compatible with cygwin. As far as I'm aware there is no way to create a linux venv on windows. Why do you need to start the venv with cygwin? If you need to use linux I would recommend using WSL or a VM

Comment: i am trying to host my flask app for which i need uwsgi to run on windows, uwsgi is supported on cygwin on windows. My flask env should be activated to run my uwsgi and my app together. I would be thankful if you tell me a solution to make it work on windows. @ben

Comment: Take a look at this page:
https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/deploying/uwsgi/  
There is an option for using a virtual env called `--virtualenv /path/to/virtual/environment` .

Comment: You must change the line endings from CR-LF to LF only. Any decent text editor should be able to do this or in Cygwin use `dos2unix FILENAME`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Doug suggested , changing CR-LF to LF did worked.
The error was due to difference in line endings.

**Unix systems** (Linux and Mac) default to the **LF** (line feed) character for line breaks.
**Windows** on the other hand is “special” and defaults to **CR/LF** (carriage return AND line feed).

If you are using **vscode** like me: Then there is CRLF written at the bottom of vscode[image]

By clicking there you can change **activate** file from CRLFto LF and it will remove the error you are facing.